# A required class was missing while executing

Tags: java, maven, automation, maven-3

I am trying to create a plugin to HP OO, when i try to compile my projects i get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-
contentpack-plugin of goal com.hp.oo.sdk:oo-contentpack-maven-plugin:5.213:gener
ate-contentpack failed: A required class was missing while executing com.hp.oo.s
dk:oo-contentpack-maven-plugin:5.213:generate-contentpack: org/sonatype/aether/r
epository/LocalRepositoryManager
```

I have tried, mvn clean install, mvn clean compile. Tried to delete the folder in repository:
org\sonatype\aether\aether-api\1.13 to force it to re-download but it still not working, anyone knows why this is happening? I have no experience with maven and not to much with java, but i don't think it is anything wrong with the code. I do believe this i a maven/dependency issue.

My maven version is 3.1.0 and java version is 1.7.0_17.

Edit:
According to another user this project should work and build fine. I get the same error on this project. [Link to project.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31609552/oo-jruby-script.zip)

This is from one of the project POM.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.todorovdi</groupId>
<artifactId>oo-its-plugin-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>OO ITS Plugin Project</name>
<url>http://www.ontario.ca/</url>

<properties>
    <sdk.group>com.hp.oo.sdk</sdk.group>
    <sdk.version>5.213</sdk.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>oo-jruby-script</module>
    <module>oo-its-plugin-pack</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: Please show your pom file of your plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP OO SDK did not support Maven 3.1.0 at the time.
When i downgraded to Maven 3.0.5, it worked as expected.